# Nslookup question about the command "root" when in nslookup mode in Windows 10

Tags: dns

I have been recently exploring the DNS service and how things work. From my understanding if the browser does not know a certain URL that is typed by the user (ex. maps.google.com) then the DNS flow will be the following:

*Browser checks its cache => Browser checks with the OS resolver software on the device (possibly checks the host.txt file that exists on the machine if it is Windows) => Operating system contacts the ISP DNS server => ISP DNS server checks cache and then resolver software from ISP DNS server reaches a DNS Root server IP address directly (root server IPs are hard-coded in the ISP resolver) => Root server directs resolver to TLD servers (.com in our example) => TLD servers sent the resolver to Authoritative servers for the domain we asked (google.com) => Authoritative server gives us the Ip address we look for (maps.google.com)*

I am experimenting with the nslookup command in Windows 10. I do the following:

```
C:\Users\me>nslookup
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  "Here I get an Ip6 address"

>root
Default Server:  A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET
Addresses:  2001:503:ba3e::2:30
      198.41.0.4
```

Above we can see one of the root DNS servers of Verizon which is used to provide the DNS service to the users on the Internet.

My questions is:

1. The information returned from the root comamnd in the nslookup mode, where are they coming from?
2. Are these information from the cache of my PC or they are information that are saved on the DNS server that my pc is contacting to get the DNS service?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, well the 13 root a servers are the master controllers of the entire web.  They are too busy to be bothered with every request so they have replicators--hundreds of other servers that have already asked and answered your question--and got a resolved website.  They then get to answer the question on behalf of the 13 root servers--for a set amount of time.